# How do I change the tray icon color for Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

The color of the `Unread Mail` icon on my taskbar is very close to the color of the taskbar itself.  How can I change the "icon" of unread email so that I can see it easier?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure there are options to customize the icon. But I can suggest a solution. Now we can change the appearance of the taskbar to make the icon visible. Check the link [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-computer-colors#1TC=windows-7) to change the colour of the taskbar. You can also find options to enable and disable transparency.
You can also increase the intensity. Try with the different colour themes so that the icon is visible.